# grep command to find files

Tags: linux, file, find, grep, hyperlink

I'm looking for a command that use grep to search in /usr/bin for all the files who have 2 links and sort them in ascending.

The second command I'm looking for must use the first one and display just the files that contain the "x"

Thanks you

Comment: "sort them in ascending" - ascending by what? By number of references? Or by modified date? or by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do

```
find /usr/bin -links 2 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -adltr
```

modify the ls to do the sorting you require

```
find /usr/bin -links 2 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "x"
```

Files containing the "x" :)

---

If you meant: 'contain the x' as 'are executable (x appears in ls -l output), use

```
find /usr/bin -links 2 -executable -print0 | ls -adltr
```

To see only dirs:

```
find /usr/bin -links 2 -type d -executable -print0 | ls -adltr
```

To see only files:

```
find /usr/bin -links 2 -type f -executable -print0 | ls -adltr
```

**Note:** *directories get 2 links by default (`.` is a link) so you might want to look for `-links 3` with directories*

Comment: added finding exeutable files on a hunch; I'm not so sure what _`the "x"`_ would mean :)

Comment: funny result for me: perlbug :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this direct from grep, eg:

```
grep -r --include=*.py "HOSTS" .
```

will search recursively ('-r') under the current directory ('.') in all python files ('*.py') for the string "HOSTS".